# How can i add singular 'the' instead of 'a/an' before object in open graph story

Tags: facebook-opengraph

How can i replace singular 'a/an' with 'the' before object in open graph story.

I am creating a story like " X joined the discussion on Appname".
Is there any option to replace singular 'a/an' with 'the' in open graph.
Please help me...Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `og:determiner` in your OG object’s meta data (as long as your object is represented by an URL pointing to an HTML document containing OG meta tags):

> *og:determiner - The word that appears before this object's title in a sentence. An enum of (a, an, the, "", auto).* (http://ogp.me/#optional)